# Resumable uploads in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file-upload, resume-upload

A part of my iOS app is to perform uploads of large files to a server. Internet connection of my users is not always ideal.

Is there any way I can perform resumable uploads?

P.S. Request type is HTTP, but if it doesn't support it, it's possible to switch.

Comment: the tactics used would vary greatly on the protocol  FTP? SFTP? SSH? HTTP?

Comment: split the file? send (next) part of file, repeat till done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads